# Convert different extension to CSV and delimit

Tags: excel, csv, delimiter, vba

I have the following files coming from a data logger.
As such they're save under weird extension. Which force me to manually convert to CSV & delimit column A by space.

I searched high & low for a code to loop through all files in a folder and convert to csv.

But all I could find were codes for

- CSV to Txt
- Txt to xml
- xlsx to Txt

This is the closest I could find

```
Sub RenameFiles()
Dim StrFile As String, newName As String
Dim filePath As Variant
filePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
StrFile = Dir(filePath & "*2")
Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    newName = Replace(StrFile, "csv", "csv")
    Name filePath & StrFile As filePath & newName
    StrFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

The drive which I need to convert files from is shown below

C:\Users\PC04\Desktop\Rename

The extensions of my file name are in the image below
[image]

How can I convert all the file in that folder to csv & delimit "Column A" by "space"

*Update*

Code for me to delimit Column A, done with macro recording.

```
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Extension name shown below
[image]

Comment: So are the files **C**omma-**S**eparated **V**alues (i.e. CSV)?  Or are they space-separated values?  Or are they a mix of both?

Comment: Their current extension is .04 , .03 , .02 , and so on

Comment: Are you sure those are the extensions? Please double check to make sure file explorer is showing the extension names.

Comment: @L42 I uploaded a snippet to show you the extension of the files. I'm manually renaming the .12 as .csv to convert them. But I have to do this weekly for 20-30 files. So yeah a macro would help me with this mundane task.

Comment: An extension does not affect the file type - it's just a way for Windows to associate a default program with the file.  You can have a CSV file with a `txt` extension, I have even seen ones with an `xls` extension.  Conversely, you can have a tab-delimited or space-delimited file with a `csv` extension.  So what type of data do you have in the file - is it comma-separated values, or is it space-separated values, or is it a mix of both.

Comment: I think what you're currently doing is fine. Maybe use `InStrRev` to find the last dot `.` and then replace that part. As for the delimiter, it should be included when the file was created, otherwise, you will have to rewrite each line and delimit each entry.

Comment: @YowE3K They're space-separated values. Yeah I need to open them up with excel so I get the values i want easily

Comment: Your pictures look like Windows Explorer; I don't think those ".##" are file extensions. In Windows Explorer right-click one of the files and select "properties", check the "type of file" to find out it's extension. You can rename the files if you want or use vba to open each file in the folder using "IE-*", and "IW-*", etc.